# Use the OVR Utilities to detect Gear VR inputs

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I'm pretty newbie in developping gear VR applications, so i really need help about the procedure to create a Gear VR app from 0.
I Use the Gear VR compatible with galaxy S6 (not the most recent one so..!).

Currently, I have my terrain, and the Occulus Utilities 5 in my project.
When i use a standard camera, a OVRCameraRig or OVRPlayerController I succeed to get the camera following head orientation (obviously, it's automatic...), but after that i can't move the camera with the DPad...

What is the procedure (prefab to use, scripts to attach, modify) to get this working and get my camera following head rotation AND touchpad swipes (can be with OVR Utilities or without)? I didn't really found something really complete about this (documentation seems to be ... fuzzy to me)
I only want to use the integrated touchpad of the GearVR, detecting taps, swipes...

The only way I succeed to get it working was to use the classic unity Input (GetMouseButtonDown(0) and GetAxis(Mouse X)). But I'm not sure that it's the correct way to do this.

Many Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

To actually benefit from the OVRInput class, you should ensure you have an OVRManager component active in the scene. It is already included into the OVRCameraRigPrefab. If you are using a custom hierarchy add it somewhere since it's a singleton.

Also, you can't apply transfomations onto the camera in VR, you should translations and rotations to it's root container.